# Discard combining in AJAX Control Toolkit Release July 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls, ajaxcontroltoolkit

CodePlex's AjaxControlToolkit release of July 2013 [introducing control bundles](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2013/07/25/july-2013-release-of-the-ajax-control-toolkit).

Ok, you can define the controls used by your application: this reduce the js package and improve the speed of your application.

But i have a problem with this release:

my ASP.NET website have a custom control, inherited from `AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.Editor`

```
public class MyHtmlEditor : AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.Editor, IMyInterface
{
    protected override void FillTopToolbar()
    {
        // my custom code
    }

    protected override void FillBottomToolbar()
    {
        // my custom code
    }
}
```

Until today, the control works perfectly.

After updating to latest release, the control won't work, and raise an exception.

This is the stack:

```
[Exception: Could not load control MyWebSite.MyHtmlEditor.
The script reference(s) of this control was not loaded correctly.
If AjaxControlToolkit.config is used, probably this control is not registered properly.]

AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +722
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +113
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4297
```

I do not need this new feature, and I do not understand why there is no explicit way to activate it (so disabled by default).

Does anyone have more of my knowledge on this?

I need to disable this new functionality, without going to the old release ..

All help will be appreciated

**EDIT**

Client script combining works only if the file `AjaxControlToolkit.config` exists,

otherwise it will load all scripts (default scenario).

After some tests of configuration, the same error is throwed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an "*issue*" in the codebase of AjaxControlToolkit July 2013 release in the way controls are resolved from **Control Bundles**.

I experienced the same issue as you have in my project after upgrading from Codeplex. 
This is my issue and context.

- I have many custom controls using and inheriting from AjaxControlToolkit resources and scripts
- Custom controls are in a second assembly
- Each one has a ClientScriptResource and dependencies on third custom controls

so after upgrading, I created the **AjaxControlToolkit.config** to register custom controls, and there has started my hours of debugging and suffering.
Without more words about the context, this are steps:

1. Create a **AjaxControlToolkit.config** as said in the Question EDIT above
2. Create a control bundle with name or not, you knows
3. For custom controls, it's needed as it's clear, to specify control assembly and control name `<control name="mynamespace.ModalPopupExtender" assembly="myassembly"></control>`
4. Refer in the page with the `TooliktScriptManager` the bundle by instert this `<ControlBundles>
           <act:ControlBundle Name="ModalPanelBundle"/>
       </ControlBundles>`

But wait here come the frustration, the AjaxControlToolkit resolves controls by assembly (as written in assembly attribute of the bundle tag) and by ***concatenating*** the assembly attribute value with the control name attribute value, so, if for example you have the control has the full namespace different form the assembly name, here you will get the exception!

There are two way to resolve the issue, **soft** and **hard**

### soft

change the namespace of the control to reflect the assembly name part and then configure the control in the bundle to obtain a right type resoluiton: eg.

**from** `<control name="Tools.Web.UI.WebControls.ModalPopupExtender" assembly="CompanyX.ProjectY"></control>`

**to** `<control name="UI.WebControls.ModalPopupExtender" assembly="CompanyX.ProjectY"></control>`

and then in the code

**from** `namespace Tools.Web.UI.WebControls.ModalPopupExtender {.. public class ModalPopupExtender {} ...}`

**to** `namespace CompanyX.ProjectY.UI.WebControls.ModalPopupExtender {.. public class ModalPopupExtender {} ...}`

### hard

1. Download the AjaxControlToolkit source code
2. Open the solution and then locate the **AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManagerConfig** class
3. At line 159, modify `ToolkitScriptManagerHelper.GetAssembly(control.Assembly)
                      .GetType(control.Assembly + "." + control.Name));` to `ToolkitScriptManagerHelper.GetAssembly(control.Assembly)
                      .GetType(control.Name));`
4. Save, close VS2012, and then rebuild using the batch for your platform

With the hard way, control resolution is done by name attribtribu, so there you can specify the full namespace name.

If the hard way is too hard, you can contact me to get the modified bins.
After the hard way applied, everything works fine for me again!

Today I suggested and opened an issue on the AjaxControlToolkit codeplex site about that.

Comment: Thanks for the very great answer, detailed and clear. I accepted the answer because it offers the solution to the problem, but unfortunately in my case I have not solved ...
My controls are all within the App_Code folder ...
Probably, in addition to one of the two solutions you provided, I'll put the controls in a separate assembly to resolve.
Thanks again

Comment: Could you add a link to the issue so we can vote on it, and see its status?